# No encuentro el error parse error

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código en php:

```
<?php
include ("conex.php");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $centro = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['centro']);
    $descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['descripcion']);
    if($centro<> "" and $descripcion <> "")
    {
        session_start();
        $congregacion = $_SESSION['congregacion'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO centros_salidas (id_centro, id_congregacion, nombre, descripcion) VALUES (NULL, '$congregacion', '$centro', '$descripcion')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)){
            mysqli_close( $con);
            $html= 1;
        }else{
            mysqli_close($con);
            $html= 0;
        }
    }else{
        $html.= 2;
    }   
    echo $html;
}   
?>
```

Obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\AppServ\www\Control_territorios\php\reg_territorio.php on line 25.

y la verdad estoy buscando a ver si me hace falta alguna { o algún ; pero no veo que me haga falta nada, es más el error me dice que esta en línea 25 la cual es el fin del script no se que pueda ser.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Elimina esto **aAg**  de tu linea de codigo. Me parece que esto es lo que te ocasiona el error.

Comment: eso no lo tengo en el codigo

Comment: Bueno al menos es lo que veo aparece el codigo que colocaste, me parece que es la linea 19.

Comment: El único error de sintaxis que tiene tu archivo es el **aAg** que aparece efectivamente en el código que has compartido. No hay ningún otro desde el punto de vista de la sintaxis. Activa la opción de *ver los caracteres invisibles* en tu editor... Supongo que al escribir la pregunta copiaste y pegaste el código, y si te fijas **aAg** sí sale en el código aquí, por lo que es muy probable que esté ahí, aunque no lo veas. Revisa también el archivo `conex.php`, ya que lo estás incluyendo.

Comment: Aunque el operador esta bien escrito, en el último else prueba a dejarlo `$html=2;`, mas que nada porque es como tienes las cosas en los anteriores condicionales

Comment: Lo unico que hacia falta el una la llave que cierra el if principal, problema resuleto, gracias a todos los que dieron sus comentarios.

Comment: Lo unico que hacia falta el una la llave que cierra el if principal, problema resuleto, gracias a todos los que dieron sus comentarios.

Answer (score 3):

Como te dicen los comentarios, el problema es que se te han colado los caracteres `aAg` en la línea 19. Elimínalo y debería funcionar.

También te recomiendo eliminar la etiqueta final de cierre de php `?>` no es necesaria y puede darte fallos alguna vez.